# How to check p2 logs?

Tags: eclipse, osgi, equinox, p2

My eclipse product installation is failing due to some p2 issues. It is not generating the bundles.info file. Is there any was we can enable to p2 log?

Or p2 logs are available at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P2 will write logs into Eclipse's log file, which always can be found from `<workspace>/.metadata/.log`.

Or you can print Eclipse's logs in your console when launching Eclipse with options `-console -consoleLog`.